# how to replace slashes with dashes and set it an environment variable in github actions

Tags: github-actions

I am trying to use a combination of branch name and github run number as the image tag in my github actions ci/cd process

Long story short: I want to have MODIFIED_BRANCH_NAME set as an environment variable and use it later

this is my workflow file

```
name: CI/CD mktplc-catalog

on:
  push:
env:
  BRANCH_NAME: ${{ github.head_ref || github.ref_name }}
  MODIFIED_BRANCH_NAME: # What goes here?
.
.
.
```

suppose the branch name is `feature/add-foo` I need MODIFIED_BRANCH_NAME to be set as `feature-add-foo`

How should I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) adding an extra step, like:

```
    steps:
      - name: Sets MODIFIED_BRANCH_NAME
        env:
          name: "${{env.BRANCH_NAME}}"
        run: |
          echo "MODIFIED_BRANCH_NAME=${name/\//-}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

Tested here https://github.com/mbiagetti/github-action-poc/pull/1

You could test shell expansion with the code:

```
>name=feature/add-foo
>MODIFIED_BRANCH_NAME=${name/\//-}
>echo $MODIFIED_BRANCH_NAME
feature-add-foo
```

### UPDATE

For multiple jobs requirement, check this PR https://github.com/mbiagetti/github-action-poc/pull/2

Comment: can I not avoid adding a step and doing it in the env inline?

Comment: I want to use it in multiple jobs

Comment: I didn't find anything on the [marketplace](https://github.com/marketplace)

Comment: you should gather in a jobs and set as output then use in the other jobs and mark that job required (needed)

Comment: should I echo it later like this? 
      - name: my-echo
        run: echo "$MODIFIED_BRANCH_NAME"

Comment: oh sorry! you're right, I miss to surround with double braced see my update

Comment: @AminBa you can check my update (see also the PR linked to the answer)

Comment: if you add another job like test2-job and try to echo the MODIFIED_BRANCH_NAME, it wont work

Comment: sure, jobs does not share env, let me propose another solution

Comment: @AminBa see if my update satisfy your requirements https://github.com/mbiagetti/github-action-poc/pull/2

Comment: I dont know why but I get this error

`/apps/ghe-actions/_work/_temp/6d98bc45-2c94-4215-b838-547edb4d69d6.sh: line 1: ${GITHUB_OUTPUT}: ambiguous redirect`

Comment: what else I tried: "${GITHUB_OUTPUT}" and $env:GITHUB_OUTPUT , etc

Comment: https://github.com/nektos/act/issues/1442

Comment: also tried `echo '::set-output name=MODIFIED_BRANCH_NAME::${name/\//-}'` and the syntax is not right

Comment: Oh I used a container and this time I got `/__w/_temp/1d5abfa8-b6dd-4ce2-adfd-54102f0dcd2a.sh: 1: Bad substitution`